# Detecting windows in openCV

Tags: opencv, object-recognition

I am trying to detect windows (real-life-house-windows). Using corner detection is not always enough. So I am trying to figure out a pattern to recognize windows.. I thought that also detecting the light difference (sun coming from the window) may be a good idea. However I couldn't differentiate that data. Would you please share your ideas about what particular features I can define for the pattern for detecting windows?

Comment: Some pictures of your particular windows would be helpful. Also some code for what you have tried would be good.

Comment: As @B suggested, go for a classification scheme where you are feeding training data and construction a classifier out of it. Cheers.